# How should our FAQ look like?

Tags: discussion

**How should our FAQ look like?**

One suggestion per answer.

Comment: We should look at all stackexchange sites' FAQs, look here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/ and make some good mix.

Comment: @ChrisJesterYoung Why did you tag this [meta-tag:faq]? That tag is for posts that themselves are FAQs.

Comment: @Doorknob The answers here are FAQ, or were intended to be. Should they be migrated to their own separate posts (that are tagged as [tag:faq])? Perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

**What is a code golf?**

A code golf is a challenge to solve the problem using the shortest code possible. Different contests use different criteria:

- Shortest source code, or shortest any code (including object code)? The former will usually exclude assembly-language entries.
- Is the length counted in bytes or Unicode code points (or something else :-O)?
- How are shell-bang lines counted? How are any command-line arguments required counted?

Comment: Your second point on byte-counting is rather tricky when actual physical encodings are brought into the matter. I don’t really think you can count bytes because you don’t know the encoding, and this can make a tremendous difference. Just consider UTF-16 alone: is it with or without BOM? Do we really want ASCII characters to count as two bytes? I think you have to count logical Unicode code points, not bytes.  Even the CRLF vs LF issue is sticky, and not easily addressed.

Answer (score 1):

**Should subjective questions be encouraged?**

[Replace this with actual policy once we have it. Discussion follows.]

Code golf is clear-cut (to a point; see [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-our-faq-look-like/3#3) for more details): as long as the rules are unambiguous, it's clear to see which entry wins.

However, a number of early questions on this site sought "creative" solutions. This is much more subjective to judge, and could simply become a "whatever the OP likes best" question, which is not what Stack Exchange is designed for, IMO.

Therefore, we should have a policy on what level of subjectiveness should be encouraged, and/or allowed.

Comment: I'm against questions that must be judged on subjective metrics.

Comment: @dmckee: +1 I couldn't agree more. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**What is the scope of CodeGolf.SE?**

*[The site (if not domain) has been renamed "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf", so this entry may well be redundant. I'm keeping it here for posterity.]*

CodeGolf.SE is the site for [code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-our-faq-look-like/3#3) and other programming puzzles. We use the name CodeGolf.SE for two reasons:

1. "Code golf" is [the most popular kind of coding game on Stack Overflow](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/site-title-and-domain/81#81), so CodeGolf.SE should appeal to that crowd
2. CodeGolf.SE is *much* easier to say and type than CodeGolfAndProgrammingPuzzles.SE.

When writing a question, please tag it with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) if it's a golfing question, and [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) if it's not.

Comment: (Please feel free to update the tags and/or the "mission statement" to reflect current consensus.)

Answer (score 0):

**Why do the number of characters matter?**

(someone else would have to fill this in since I'm not really convinced this is super important)

Comment: This one's easy! This site is "Code Golf & Programming Puzzles". That means at least 50% of the site's charter is code golfing. _By definition_, code golf is a contest for the shortest code to solve a problem: in real golf, you want to get the ball into the hole with fewest strokes; in code golf, you want to solve the problem with fewest (key)strokes.

Comment: As for why code golf has value: it's instantly obvious which solution is "best"---just look at its size! It's totally objective, and there is no dispute as to which answer should win.

Comment: Just for the record: if the winning criterion is not "shortest code", then it is not a code golf, and should not be called one.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young, what if it's "fewest semi-colons" or some other arbitrary measure to be minimized? It might not be true `code golf` but it would be kinda "golfy" to coin a phrase.