# Site title and domain

Tags: discussion, scope, site-name

The area51 proposal was titled "Code Golf & Programming Challenges" and the discussion on area51 even nudged towards making it just "Programming Challenges" so that it has wider scope. Yet the title here is "Code Golf" and the domain codegolf.se.com.

Why the sudden shift back to Code Golf only? Should we change it to Programming Challenges?

Comment: why not just "puzzles" or "puzzles overflow"? It is rather obvious that SE network is programming biased, it is a searching/profiling problem to find the programming -biased problems or codegolfing for certain audiences. Develop the search for profiling this site for wider audience... "programming challenges" taste vague. I cannot understand **the discrimination of the non-programming puzzlers**, needs just good mods to kill the junk and good ideas/guidelines to manage this site with wider audience. Very well, there are gaming and play-boaard SEs  -- no general site like stackoverflow?

Answer (score 17):

I personally I dislike both `codegolf.se` and `challenges.se` as names. The former is too specific and the latter isn't specific enough. I think the name of this `stackexchange` needs to contain synonyms of the words `code` **and** `challenge`.

So I have a few suggestions:

- `codegames`
- `codinggames`
- `codecontest`
- `codeduel`
- `codeoff`
- `codingfun` (from marcog's [post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/site-title-and-domain/125#125))

Comment: How about `codinghorror`...? No wait - that's taken :)

Comment: +1 for codegames.

Answer (score 12):

> challenges.stackexchange.com

is utterly meaningless compared to

> codegolf.stackexchange.com

Come to our site for.. uh.. er.. CHALLENGES! Code Golf means something to the intended audience, "challenges" does not.

That said, I **totally support clarifying (via the FAQ) that  Code Golf includes ALL programming puzzles not just shortest code**.

Comment: I get the point you're trying to make about challenges.se (I'll ponder a better alternative), but I disagree with your reasoning for codegolf.se. We're already seeing that encourages people to golf non-golf questions ([one of many examples](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266/nokia-mystery-puzzle/279#279)). I don't think clarifying it in the faq is sufficient.

Comment: I personally don't think either is a good name. I think the name should contain the word `code` or one of it's synonyms, but `codegolf` is too specific. `codejam` would have been cool, but there are very clear trademark violations.

Comment: More confusion observed in the comments here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39/fast-line-drawing-algorithm

Comment: @marcog incorrect; that is about whether or not performance is a valid "puzzle". I tend to agree that it is not a puzzle.

Comment: @Jeff That's a valid question and I take your side in it being more relevant for SO. Look past it though and you'll see confusion over the name: "Codegolf is about short code, not fast code or optimizing for speed" (he didn't refer to puzzles; a similar comment could be made on an obfuscation question, which is definitely an on-topic puzzle) and "Then why is this site named Code Golf?" (very clear reference to the naming problem). That's how I interpret it at least.

Comment: @Jeff: I just added [an entry](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-our-faq-look-like/179#179) to the proposed FAQ that describes how CodeGolf.SE covers both code golf and other programming puzzles, and why we are just called CodeGolf.SE. Hopefully this has enough clarity. We'll see. :-)

Comment: @marcog: I posted a FAQ entry describing why we currently use CodeGolf.SE. Please feel free to update it with current consensus re naming, scope, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I'm thinking of something along the lines of codingfun. It's short and gets across that this site is about coding for fun, which don't think any challenge/puzzle is not. Question is, is there too much outside our scope that would fall into coding for fun? I can't really think of anything major that goes against this site's purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I think that we *should* invite games and contests other than golf, so the title from the Area51 proposal made sense to me.

As for the domain...well, golf was the only game with wide acceptance on Stack Overflow, and *I* saw this proposal as a way of getting it off without hurting peoples feelings.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this and would like to propose the following:

- Name: Programming Challenges
- Domain: challenges.stackexchange.com
- Tagline: Programming Challenges - Stack Exchange is for programmers looking for a challenge

Code golf is a type of programming challenge, the challenge being to come up with the shortest code. I prefer *challenges* over *puzzles* because we don't seem to have any of the latter (at least not yet).

Comment: I agree with the proposal.

Comment: Ok I retract that on second thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

## CodeSport?

or .. um .. Code-thletics? :(

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I was surprised to see the codegolf domain when I received the beta email.

Having said that however I cannot think of a programming challenge (puzzle) that could not be run as a codegolf question so I believe it may be a moot-point.

Comment: If it's a programming challenge, OP is interested in solutions and a description of the solution. Shortest code is not needed here, so why make it a shortest code contest always?

Comment: @marcog, I agree. Its early and I didn't think of that. I rescind my above statement about it being a moot-point